# iCheck with AngularJS and RequireJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, icheck

I've looked around stackoverflow as well as read [this thread](https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/issues/62) but still no success. I am trying to use iCheck in my AngularJS web app but I am still only seeing regular checkboxes. I am also using require.js. Any ideas how to get this to work?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<label ng-disabled="true" style="font-weight:normal">
                        <input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="permissions[0]"
                               ng-disabled="true" ng-checked="user.isAdmin" />&emsp;Option #1<br />
                    </label>
                    <label ng-disabled="true" style="font-weight:normal">
                        <input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="permissions[1]"
                               ng-disabled="true" ng-checked="user.isAdmin" />&emsp;Option #2<br />
                    </label>
                    <label ng-disabled="true" style="font-weight:normal">
                        <input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="permissions[2]"
                               ng-disabled="true" ng-checked="user.isAdmin" />&emsp;Option #3<br />
                    </label>
                    <label ng-disabled="true" style="font-weight:normal">
                        <input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="permissions[3]"
                               ng-disabled="true" ng-checked="user.isAdmin" />&emsp;Option #4<br />
                    </label>
                    <label ng-disabled="true" style="font-weight:normal">
                        <input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="permissions[4]"
                               ng-disabled="true" ng-checked="user.isAdmin" />&emsp;Option #5<br />
                    </label>
```

Directive (from https://github.com/ciel/icheck):

```
    (function () {
    /**
     * Create a new module for icheck so that it can be injected into an existing
     * angular program easily.
     */
    angular.module('ui.check', [])
      .directive('icheck', function ($timeout, $parse) {
          return {
              require: 'ngModel',
              link: function ($scope, element, $attrs, ngModel) {
                  return $timeout(function () {
                      var value;
                      value = $attrs['value'];

                      $scope.$watch($attrs['ngModel'], function (newValue) {
                          $(element).iCheck('update');
                      });

                      return $(element).iCheck({
                          checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
                          radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'

                      }).on('ifChanged', function (event) {
                          if ($(element).attr('type') === 'checkbox' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                              $scope.$apply(function () {
                                  return ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.checked);
                              });
                          }
                          if ($(element).attr('type') === 'radio' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
                              return $scope.$apply(function () {
                                  return ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
                              });
                          }
                      });
                  });
              }
          };
      });
})();
```

Comment: Did you resolve you'r problem ?

Comment: I never resolved my question, however I opted to use my own CSS style for checkboxes and radio buttons instead of iCheck.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you're loading the iCheck component in your main html file:

`<script src="bower_components/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Check that in your main angular module you'r importing

```
ui.check
```

Like

```
angular.module("myApp",['ui.check'])
```